# How to bring a variable from the .py file to the .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Kv language has a way to import names from other files using the following syntax:

```
#:import name x.y.z

# The same as `from x.y import z as name` in Python code
```

But it doesn't mention how to import the values from the same module where that kv language is used.
Let's say I have the following code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.atlas import Atlas
from kivy.uix.button import Button

theme = Atlas('path/to/atlas')

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    background_normal: theme['widget_bg']
''')

class MyWidget(Button):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return MyWidget() 

TestApp().run()
```

I'd like to import the `theme` Atlas object into the kv code to set the proper background. How could this be done?

Comment: try using `root.theme` in your .kv file wherever you need to use that variable.

Comment: @GeorgeBou `root` refers to the current root widget, I don't think it has anything to do with the global namespace

Comment: you can pass the global variable in the widget as well... doesn't that work for you?

Comment: @GeorgeBou No, the point is to have it global. I'd like to use it in multiple places in .py code, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to your current module as __main__

```
#:import theme __main__.theme

<MyWidget>:
   background_normal: theme['widget_bg']
```